# C# directed broadcast

Tags: .net, networking, udp, udpclient

I'm writing a client for a hardware device that communicates via UDP. I want to auto-discover the device's IP address.

I snooped another client's traffic and saw that it sends a directed broadcast, e.g. 192.168.1.255. The device responds and the client has the device's IP.

If I do the same it works fine. I see the broadcast message and the device's response in Wireshark, and my app receives data:

```
var client = new UdpClient() { EnableBroadcast = true };
//...
client.Send(data, data.Length, "192.168.1.255", serverPort);
```

[image: wireshark packets]

However, this is a cross platform mobile app where getting access to network details is a pain in the ass, so rather than doing a *directed* broadcast (where I need to know the IP and subnet mask), I tried a local broadcast (255.255.255.255):

```
var client = new UdpClient() { EnableBroadcast = true };
//...
client.Send(data, data.Length, "255.255.255.255", serverPort);
```

But.. this sends nothing. I see nothing in Wireshark when I do this, and I get no response from the device. The only change to my code is that one string.

Does anyone know why this is? Is there any way via .NET to do a directed broadcast without calculating the IP myself?

Comment: That is a misuse of broadcast, and many companies will now reject such applications, and broadcast has been eliminated from IPv6, so you could not port such and application to IPv6 when needed. The modern way to do this is to have the target subscribe to a specific multicast group, and the device searching for the target can send a message to the multicast group. The target will then have the unicast address of the searcher to which it can reply with its own unicast address.

Comment: That may be true, but doesn't really help me. I can't change how this device operates. It's a *very* popular commercial product which has been on the market for years, so there are tons of them in the wild and they aren't changing any time soon. Is almost always operated on a dedicated network (i.e. the only devices on the network are this hardware and its clients). The official clients (published on all major platforms, desktop and mobile) find the device on the network via a directed broadcast, as shown.

Comment: Multicast also uses UDP, it is a subscribed broadcast that only interrupts devices subscribing to the group, but broadcast interrupts every device on the network. If you wanted to sell that to my company, or many others, it would fail the lab test because broadcast can be a security problem, and unnecessary broadcasts use unnecessary bandwidth on the network that can be used for legitimate traffic. You would also not be able to do that for an IPv6 client. We are heading toward eliminating IPv4 from out network, and others are doing the same thing, and every application must be IPv6 compatible.

Comment: Again, all of that may be true, but it's not relevant to my question. The device already exists in the market. It doesn't use multicast, and only operates on dedicated networks. Its clients, which are on Windows, OSX, iOS, and Android, all find the device via broadcast. My question has nothing to do with what your company will or will not buy, lab tests, security, bandwidth, or the future of IPv4.

Comment: Apple will require your iOS software to work with IPv6 (Apple will test the application on an IPv6-only network), and that doesn't have broadcast. By the way, a directed broadcast is one that is sent from one network to a different network, and routers default to dropping that. The terms you want are network broadcast (the `192.168.1.255`), and limited broadcast (the `255.255.255.255`),

Comment: Apple doesn't test with this device (they don't have it). The device's official client, which is on the App Store, finds the device via broadcast. Again, neither Apple nor IPv6 is relevant to the question; the question is about an IPv4 mechanism on an IPv4 device. I appreciate the additional info, but it seems as if you're trying to dissuade me from using broadcast at all, which makes no sense in this context.